# What does value mean in relation to python objects?

Tags: python

I am reading python's language reference and in the 3rd chapter 'Data model' it is said that every object has an identity, type and value. The identity I understood. The type I guess means the object referenced by `__class__` (please correct if wrong). I guess that value means the attributes of the object, or in other words the objects referenced by the names in the object's namespace. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Most of the time, just think of the value as the object itself.

You could also use the word 'state' to describe the object value; for mutable objects the value can *change*, but in general the object, it's type and identity, do not change.

Some examples:

- `2048` is an `int` with the integer value 2048. `int` is an immutable type, so the value will never change. You generally create a *new* object of the same type with a different value; `2048 + 1` produces a new `int` object with value 2049, with a new identity.
- `[42]` is a list with a single reference to another object. You can change the contents, changing the list value. But the identity and type would not change.
- For instances of a Python class, `__class__` is writable, letting you change the type dynamically. This is rarely needed, but the option exists.

Comment: but what if I write a = C(), where C is some class, and then a.__class__ = B, where B is another class. Have I not changed a's type then? This is in relation to your statement that the type and identity do not change.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев: yup, but only for Python classes; you can't do the same for `int` or `str` or `list`.